# How can I create a Generator in ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby

How can I made this part of code from Javascript to Ruby? I would like to translate from Javascript to Ruby this function:

```
function* generate(arr) {
    console.log('AAAA'+ arr)
    const A = Array.from(arr); // copy
    const len = A.length;
    const c = new Array(len).fill(0);
    let i = 0;
    yield A;
  
    while (i < len) {
        if (c[i] < i) {
            let j = i & 1 ? c[i] : 0;

            if (A[i] != A[j]) {
                [A[j], A[i]] = [A[i], A[j]];
                yield A;
            }

            c[i]++;
            i = 0;
        } 
        else {
            c[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
};
```

I am using like this that function:

```
function* definition(data) {
    const state = data.map(v => generate(v));
```

and definition function i am using like this:

```
arr= [
  ['1','2','1','2','1'],
  ['2','2','2','4','4'],
]
state = definition(arr)
console.log('STATE',state)
```

this console getting this:

STATE[object Generator],[object Generator],[object Generator]
the console show me this:

```
AAAA1,1,1,2,1
AAAA3,2,4,4,4
AAAA6,6,7,8,7
```

I was trying this is my attempt:

```
def generate(arr)      
  a = arr.clone
  len = a.size
  c = new Array(len).fill(0)
  let i = 0
  yield a

  while i < len 
    if(c[i] < i) 
      let j = i&1 ? c[i] : 0

      if (a[i] != a[j]) 
        a[j], a[i] = [a[i], a[j]]
        yield a
      end

      c[i]++
      i = 0
    else 
      c[i] = 0
      i++
    end
  end
end
```

In Ruby I am using like this:

```
def definition(data)
  state = data.map { |v| generate(v) }
```

But I need a function* in ruby to create a **generator.**

also, this `new Array(len).fill(0)` is ok?

Comment: What do you mean a generator? What is the intended usage here and what is the intended result (in ruby)

Comment: @engineersmnky he's talking about a Generator object in JS.

@thedo looks like you're missing some code here to show us context. Where is `arr` assigned? And where are you calling `generate`?

Comment: @jeffdill2 i made a change in my question

Comment: You can write `new Array(len).fill(0)` either as `Array.new(len).fill(0)` or `[0] * 10`

Comment: @thedo you still don't show where `arr` is assigned or where `generate` is called.

Comment: What is the desired output? I don't write much JS and your `console.log` seems to occur prior to the execution of any of the actual logic. Can you please post something like: When I have an array of X and I pass it to the `generate` method I expect the result to be Y?

Comment: @jeffdill2 thank you, not a JS person. Can you confirm that JS `yield` is akin to ruby `yield` e.g. passes an object to a block? and in the case of the JS it appears to pass `A` to the same block twice? (or at least this is how it would work in ruby)

Comment: You should start the question with an explanation, in words, of what the generate does, followed by one or more examples if you think that would help readers understand how it works. That has two benefits: 1) it would help those familiar with Javascript to decipher your code; and 2) it would allow those familiar with Ruby but not Javascript to contribute answers.

Comment: @engineersmnky Not at all, JS `yield` is more like `yielder.yield` in `Enumerator.new { |yielder| }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here JS generator function

```
function* generator() {
  let i = 0

  while (true) {
    yield i++
  }
}

gen = generator()

console.log(gen.next().value) // will print 0
console.log(gen.next().value) // will print 1
console.log(gen.next().value) // will print 2
// etc.
```

And here Ruby analogue to understanding

```
def generator
  Enumerator.new do |enum|
    i = 0

    loop do
      enum.yield i
      i += 1
    end
  end
end

gen = generator

puts gen.next # will print 0
puts gen.next # will print 1
puts gen.next # will print 2
# etc.
```

Comment: please help me traslating whole function js to ruby

Comment: In 2.7 ruby introduced [`Enumerator#produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce), which was much needed in my opinion, and will simplify your Enumerator to `Enumerator.produce(0,&:succ)`

Comment: I would then use `Integer#next` method in this case like `Enumerator.produce(0, &:next)`. In my opinion semantically it's better in this case

Comment: @mechnicov same difference they are actually just aliases (both call `rb_int_succ(VALUE num)` internally.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
generator = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  5.times do
    5.times do |i|
      yielder << i
    end
  end
end

generator.to_a
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# Or use different methods from Enumerator or Enumerable
# Or make a function that returns this Enumerator for
# closest approximation of what you do with JS
```

In general, Ruby has no concept of `*` functions or `async`. You should think of them as if ALL Ruby functions were `async` and ALL calls were `await`. What this means is that unlike in JavaScript, in Ruby you can abort execution at any time, using a low-level interface of `Fiber`, or high-level abstractions like aforementioned Enumerator::Generator (created with Enumerator.new).

Comment: why 5? i need dinamyc size

Comment: @thedo: "why 5? i need dinamyc size" – This is called a "simplified example".